# How to select a column's values from a dataframe based on a datetime condition in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my first time using stack overflow, and I still don't know how to properly add code lines so excuse me.

The title might not explain enough the problem I'm stuck with. I have a first dataframe (let's call it `df1`) that contains a column of datetimes for each hour since 1990 and another column for wave height. I created another dataframe (`df2`) with the start & end date & duration of the **slot** where the wave height doesn't surpass a certain value.

What I would like to achieve now, is simply adding the `mean()` of the wave height in **each available slot** to my df2. However, since the wave height to all the dates (including those where waveheight > my value condition) are in df1, I don't seem to find the appropriate method to iterate into my df1 and select into df2 only the wave height values where (start date <= df1.time <= end date) for each slot. I'm able to do it for **only one slot** for the moment.

I'm still new to the Pandas logic, I know that we should avoid using loops but I can't see how to achieve my goal without looping.

Comment: Hi! It would help a lot if you could provide sample data for both df1 and df2. Then rephrase the question with reference to sample data. In this way it will be much easier to understand and provide answers to the question. Maybe this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61656042/pandas-dataframe-mean-of-data-in-columns-occurring-before-certain-date-time

Answer (score 0):

Answer this is a little complicated without a data sample. Assuming your df1 would be something like this:

```
    date; value
    1990-01-01 03:20:00; 278.2 
    1990-01-01 15:30:00; 280.0
    1990-01-01 19:00:00; 281.1
    1990-01-02 02:00:00; 279.2
.
.
.
```

And then, your df2 would be this:

```
start; end; mean
1990-01-01 00:00:00; 1990-01-02 00:00:00; 280.4
1990-01-02 00:00:00; 1990-01-05 00:00:00; 277.9
.
.
.
```

So, you want to fill the mean column in df2 using data from df1. You can define a function and then apply this function to df2 lines, so you can search the values in df1 and then calculate the mean.

```
def func_mean(line):
    line['mean'] = df1[(df1['date'] > line['start']) & (df1['date'] < line['end'])]['value'].mean()
    return line
```

Apply this function to df2 rows:

```
new_df = df2.apply(func_mean, axis=0)
```